# In legend of Dygraphs, can we show first Y value and then X value?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Can we show first Y value and then X value?
Legend is rounded in below image.
107.58 is Y axis value and 01-20-2017 07.20AM is X value..
Can we interchange those two values in Dygraphs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using dygraphs 2, you can do this with a [`legendFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#legendFormatter).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function legendFormatter(data) {
  if (data.x == null) return '';  // no selection

  const yHTML = data.series.map(v => v.labelHTML + ': ' + v.yHTML).join(' ');
  return yHTML +' ' + data.xHTML;  // y, then x
}

new Dygraph(div, data, { legendFormatter });
```